# How to convert torrent info hash for scrape Using php?

Tags: php, bittorrent, seed, tracker, peer

Can anyone explain me how to write a php script to convert info hash for scrape to get seeders and peers count from the tracker...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272202/3155632 to convert info hash of  a torrent for scrape

or use this :

   `//Torrent hash = bc801b9d9972c432decafe56410f092e5de15ea6
   $packed_hash = urlencode( pack('H*', $hash_info ? $hash_info  :'bc801b9d9972c432decafe56410f092e5de15ea6' ) );
   echo $packed_hash;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bitsnoop API at www.bitsnoop.com

```
http://bitsnoop.com/info/api.html
```

They have a very simple API you can use to get information about torrents.

In addition, you can combine the data you get from Bitsnoop and use

```
www.torrage.com
```

to get the download links etc.